# Custom Line structure in C#

Tags: c#, struct

I have defined a structure like this that stores X1, Y1, X2, Y2 values of a Line, I was wondering if there is a similar structure in C# and am I reinventing the wheel here?

```
public struct _2DLine
{
    public double X1 { get; set; }
    public double Y1 { get; set; }
    public double X2 { get; set; }
    public double Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**
I don't want to draw a Line, I just want to store the end points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `System.Drawing.Point` as components of your line.

```
public struct _2DLine
{
    public Point Point1 { get; set; }
    public Point Point2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this too. What about using Shapes.Line as suggested by Palak.Maheria? In my opinion it will create a lot of unnecessary overhead right?

Comment: First of all it's the overhead you mention, allot of drawing members. Then it's the namespace, `System.Drawing` is more common than `System.Windows.Shapes`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. You mean The above structure also has over head?

Comment: No, `Point` is really light, only two members.

Comment: Thanks. I used the suggested structure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this namespace System.Windows.Shapes.Line to draw line.

Comment: No I don't want to draw Line, I just want to store the values of the end points of a Line in a structure.

Comment: Obviously you can store data using the same namespace I have shown above.

Comment: I have lots of Lines, doesn't it have lots overhead to use Shapes.Line to store only these values?

Answer (score 1):

The type is simple enough that unless you are going to be passing instances to things which accept some particular structure type (in which case you should likely use that), it's probably better to define your own type than introduce a dependency on some obscure one.  Note that within a struct, public *fields* are better than public mutable properties.  This is doubly true if the constituents are, themselves, structures, as would be the case if you used two `System.Drawing.Point` (as suggested by Menelaos Vergis, and a very reasonable proposition if you'll be passing coordinates to methods that accept that type).

Using public fields rather than properties will make it possible to perform computations like `myLine.Start.X += 23;` rather than having to say `myLine.Start = new Point(myLine.Start.X+23, myLine.Start.Y);`.  Although some people who think everything should behave as a class object prefer the latter syntax, I would consider the ability to use the former to be an worthwhile advantage of using fields.  Note with class objects, properties have some real advantages over fields, but almost none of those advantages are applicable to structures, and they generally don't outweigh the more convenient updates made possible via the use of fields.